# Callback with info when popScene in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, callback, cocos2d-x

I'm new using cocos2dx, and I'm trying to create a level (scene) where you can open a sublevel (scene) without destroying the main level, so I'm using pushScene. When I finish this sublevel, I use popScene to return to the main level.

I would like to know if there is a callback method to make changes on the main level if the player wins on the sublevel, I mean, I want to pass some basic info like a bool.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I found the solution.

If you have a pushed Scene, when you use popScene with the Director, then your current Scene changes to the main Scene (in my case), so you can get it and work without problems:

```
//Bye bye sublevel
Director::getInstance()->popScene();

//Get the main level
((SuperLevel*)Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene())->probatina();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override onEnter () and onExit () built in functions. Make sure to call the parent function when you derive them:

```
void HelloWorldScene::onEnter ()
{
    Scene::onEnter ();
    //do your thing here
}
```